# I have SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 but Crystal Report Viewer is not creating its component

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

When i select crystal report viewer it is giving me the error which is visible in the image  below.When i double click on the crystal report viewer it gives me this error.   Thanks in advance

[image: Hello, When i select crystal report viewer its gives me the error which is visible in the image.When i double click on the crystal report viewer it gives me this error. Thanks in advance]

Answer (score 0):

Your form or references are still pointing to a v9 DLL (which isn't found). You need to remove the Crystal references, and point to the newer Crystal DLLs.